# aor-simple-graphql-client : error following the tutorial

Tags: reactjs, graphql, admin-on-rest

I'm trying to use aor-simple-graphql-client for admin on rest with react-boilerplate.

I got a simple error trying to create the Apollo client.

File : App.js on admin

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { restClient: null };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    createRestClient().then((restClient) => this.setState({ restClient }));
  }

  render() {
    const { restClient } = this.state;

    if (!restClient) {
      return <div>Loading</div>;
    }

    ...
```

When I navigate to localhost/admin, i get an error Uncaught (in promise) ...
restClient is never initialize. I'm pretty sure its a basic error, but i cant get it through.

Can someone can help me with that ?

My repo : https://github.com/romainquellec/cuistot

Thanks.

More on the error : Its maybe just a configuration error. I cant get the restClient initialized, liked componentDidMount is neved called.

I tried different methods, inspired on your project, with no results.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpRN5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to clone & run your project but it fails almost immediately because of missing packages. Does master have all your latest commits ?

In the meantime, can you post here the detail of your error ?

Gildas

Comment: sorry for that. The missing packages are added.

Comment: I forget to say that i'm running a postgraphql middleware. You'll get an error without a postgres db running.

You can remove everything related to postgraphql in server/index.js

sorry for that.

Comment: Yeah I had to run my postgres docker container ;)

Comment: After some digging, I've seen something strange: it seems that the graphql package (https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) which provide the introspection query is not present inside your webpack build.

Comment: Damn auto submit ^^

As it is not here on the client side, we receive an undefined introspectionQuery and this throws the error:

Syntax Error GraphQL (1:1) Unexpected Name "undefined"

Comment: I can't debug why it has not been included by webpack however. You're on your own from there

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time ! I will look into that.